# Find on $C[0,1]$ closed and bounded set $A$ that there are no such $f,g \in A$ that imply $\operatorname{diam}(A)=d(f,g)$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Find in $C[0,1]$ closed and bounded set $A$ such that there are no $f,g \in A$ that imply $\operatorname{diam}(A)=d(f,g)$, where $\operatorname{diam}(A) = \sup\{d(f,g)\mid f,g \in A\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f_n$ as:

$f_n = 1-(1/n)$  on $[1/n, 1]$, $0$ in $0$, and linear on the rest (but so that the function is continuous, basically connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $(1/n,1-(1/n))$ on the graph of function f_n).

Now when considering the set $A=\{f_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$:

$f_1$ will be costant $0$ function, and the other functions will be going up in their maximum, which will be $1-(1/n)$ - so $diam(A)=1$, but no two functions have that distance between them.

The set is bounded, and any sequence in it that isn't eventually constant, does not converge to anything in the the space of continuous functions with $sup$ metric, as the pointwise limit of such a sequence would be a function $f$ with values $0$ in $0$, and $1$ on $(0,1]$, and that is not a continuous function.

Comment: Faster by one minute! ;) One remark: I'd change the conclusion to say something along the lines of: The set $A$ is bounded by 1 and it is closed since any (not eventually constant) subsequence in it has as only possible limit the function which is constantly one (the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$). However since $f_n(0)=0$ always, there is no convergence in the $sup$ metric to $f=1$.

Comment: Just for the record, one could also use $f_n(x)=max(1-n x,0)$, again bounded and closed, with $diam=1$ but no two elements realising this distance.

Comment: You are correct, though I think the pointwise limit is $0$ at $0$ no?

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't precise enough, sorry. Looks like I can't edit the comment any longer, though

Comment: No problem, thanks for the remark.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: Stylistic nit-pick : Instead of "$0$  in  $0$", write $f_n(0)=0.$

Comment: Why A is a closed set ?

Comment: A set is closed in a metric space, if it contains all limits of a sequence in that set - you cannot 'converge out of closed set'. That is the case here, since we cannot create a sequence of elements that would converge to something outside of the set.